# Difference between public coin and common coin?

Tags: randomness

What is the difference between public coin and a common coin?

I often see both appearing in the literature, but I cannot explain myself, whether they are the same concept or not.

Comment: You're question in the title and the first sentence are add odds (public / private). Could you adjust that?

Comment: ops sorry, got confused myself!